# How do I send two byte via QSslSocket separately?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qtnetwork

I have a client program and a server program that communicate using QSslSockets. In the server program I'm sending a string `"Snameadded"` if the client successfully connected,I also want to send it a list of the users on the server, but as a different message, I make two different blocks and write them separately but they are being read by the client as one

This is the code on the server:

```
void server::processMess(QString message)
{

    //Message type legend
    // [number]*** [name]*** [message]
    // number = 1, joining server for first time, rest is name
    // number = 2, split by "***", retrive name, receiving name, and rest is message
    // number = 3, disconnecting from server, resy is name


    bool successfullyConnected = false;
    QStringList temp = message.split("***");
    int num = temp.at(0).toInt();

    qDebug() << num;
    qDebug() << "size of socket list:" << myClientSockets.size();
    QString name = temp.at(1);
    if(num == 1)
    {
        QString name = temp.at(1);
        if(clientList.contains(name))
        {
            QByteArray block;
            block.append("Enameinvalid");

            QSslSocket *clientConnection = myClientSockets.at(myClientSockets.size() - 1);
            myClientSockets.pop_back();
            clientConnection->write(block);
            \

        }
        else
        {
            clientList.append(name);
            QByteArray block;
            block.append("Snameadded");
            successfullyConnected = true;


            QSslSocket *clientConnection = myClientSockets.at(myClientSockets.size() - 1);
            qDebug() << "Message created to send back to client: " << QString(block);
            clientConnection->write(block);

           /*
            ClientThread *thisClientThread = new ClientThread();
            thisClientThread->setClientConnection(clientConnection);
            myClientThreads.push_back(thisClientThread);
            connect(thisClientThread, SIGNAL(messageReceived(QString)), this, SLOT(processMess(QString)));
            thisClientThread->start();*/

        }
    }
    else if(num == 2)
    {
        //Direct message correctly
        QString receiver = temp.at(2);
        QSslSocket* receiverConnection = myClientSockets.at(clientList.indexOf(receiver));
        QByteArray block;
        block.append(message);
        receiverConnection->write(block);

    }
    else if(num == 3)
    {
        //Disconnect client
        updateServer(name + "disconnected");
        int position = clientList.indexOf(name);
        clientList.removeAt(position);
        myClientSockets.removeAt(position);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Should never reach here";
    }

    if(successfullyConnected)
    {

        QByteArray block;
        block.append("UsersOnServer:");
        for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); ++i)
        {
            block.append(clientList.at(i));
            if(i < clientList.size() - 1)
            {
                block.append("***");
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < myClientSockets.size(); ++i)
        {
            QSslSocket *receiverConnection = myClientSockets.at(i);
            receiverConnection->write(block);
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Messaged received from client: " + message;
    updateServer("Messaged received from client: " + message);


    /*QSslSocket* thisConnection = myClientSockets.pop_back();

    QByteArray incoming = thisConnection->readAll();

    QString message = QString(incoming);

    qDebug() << "Message received from client: " + message;

    return;*/

    /*QByteArray in = tempSocket->readAll();

    QString message = QString(in);

    qDebug() << "Messaged received from client: " + message;
    updateServer(message);
*/


}
```

heres the code on my client side:
secureSocket->write(block);

```
if(secureSocket->waitForReadyRead(1000))
{
    QByteArray in = secureSocket->readAll();

    QString serverMess = QString(in);
    if(QString::compare(serverMess, "Snameadded", Qt::CaseSensitive) == 0)
    {
        returnVal = true;
        qDebug() << "added to server";
        connect(secureSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receiveMess()));
    }
    else if(QString::compare(serverMess, "Enameinvalid", Qt::CaseSensitive) == 0)
    {
        returnVal = false;
        qDebug() << "username already taken";
    }
    qDebug() << "*************Message from server:************** 1" << serverMess;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it I just did QSslSocket::waitForBytesWritten() so it would send the first byte array then the second one seperately.

Comment: Note: Stream protocols send a stream of bytes with no boundaries, no messages. So this answer is basically a hack, creating "boundary" which relies on data being delivered when `waitForBytesWritten()` returns. And this is not reliable way. The bytes could get clumped together in the network anyway, or what is sent as one write can get split up. Only way to send messages over stream is to have some kind of protocol (such as send fixed length messages, or use delimiters) on top of the byte stream, which allows separating messages.